# understanding python reference counts in order to debug c-extensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, reference-counting, python-c-extension

I am writing a c-extension and want to test it in pytest.

Part of what I am testing is whether the reference counts are correct on my objects. Thus I build a small test in pure python that puzzles me...

from Ipython i get:

```
In [1]: x = 153513514215

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: sys.getrefcount(x)
Out[3]: 2
```

So fare so good, 1 reference from assignment and 1 from the caller.

However the following script (stackoverflow_test.py) gives the following results

```
import sys

def test_ref_count_int():
    x = 677461248192962146784178
    assert sys.getrefcount(x) == 2

def test_ref_count_str():
    y = 'very long and probbably very unique string'
    assert sys.getrefcount(y) == 2

def normal_te_st():
    x = 222677461248192962146784178
    y = '!!!!very long and probbably unique string!!!!'
    print ('x refcount = {}'.format(sys.getrefcount(x)))
    print ('y refcount = {}'.format(sys.getrefcount(y)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    normal_te_st()
```

when I run it as a normal python script

```
$ python3 stackoverflow_test.py
x refcount = 4
y refcount = 4
```

Why 4 and not 2?.

When I run it with pytest

```
$ python3 -m pytest stackoverflow_test.py
=================== test session starts ===================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.3, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /opt/projects/0001_Intomics/00005_TextMining/jcr/textmining/tests, inifile:
collected 2 items

stackoverflow_test.py FF

======================== FAILURES =========================
___________________ test_ref_count_int ____________________

    def test_ref_count_int():
        x = 677461248192962146784178
>       assert sys.getrefcount(x) == 2
E       assert 3 == 2
E        +  where 3 = <built-in function getrefcount>(677461248192962146784178)
E        +    where <built-in function getrefcount> = sys.getrefcount

stackoverflow_test.py:7: AssertionError
___________________ test_ref_count_str ____________________

    def test_ref_count_str():
        y = 'very long and probbably very unique string'
>       assert sys.getrefcount(y) == 2
E       AssertionError: assert 3 == 2
E        +  where 3 = <built-in function getrefcount>('very long and probbably very unique string')
E        +    where <built-in function getrefcount> = sys.getrefcount

stackoverflow_test.py:11: AssertionError
```

Why 3 and not 2?

**Question: How come that**

- python = 4 ref counts
- pytest = 3 ref counts
- ipython session = 2 ref counts

I would expect it to behave like in ipython in all 3 cases, can anybody explain what is going on, and give me some hints how to best test the objects I am creating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literals in your code are stored in a code object. The bytecode stack is another reference:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def normal_te_st():
...     x = 222677461248192962146784178
...     y = '!!!!very long and probbably unique string!!!!'
...     print ('x refcount = {}'.format(sys.getrefcount(x)))
...     print ('y refcount = {}'.format(sys.getrefcount(y)))
...
>>> normal_te_st.__code__.co_consts
(None, 222677461248192962146784178, '!!!!very long and probbably unique string!!!!', 'x refcount = {}', 'y refcount = {}')
>>> dis.dis(normal_te_st)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (222677461248192962146784178)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('!!!!very long and probbably unique string!!!!')
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (y)

  4           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('x refcount = {}')
             12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (format)
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (sys)
             16 LOAD_ATTR                3 (getrefcount)
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 POP_TOP

  5          28 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             30 LOAD_CONST               4 ('y refcount = {}')
             32 LOAD_ATTR                1 (format)
             34 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (sys)
             36 LOAD_ATTR                3 (getrefcount)
             38 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
             40 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             42 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             44 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             46 POP_TOP
             48 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             50 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `LOAD_CONST` opcodes load the object from the `co_consts` tuple attached to the code object; that tuple is one reference. `STORE_FAST` then puts that into a local variable, that's the second reference.

Then there's the `LOAD_FAST` opcode, this takes a name from local storage and puts it on the stack, [again incrementing the reference count](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4edfc9abffca965e76ebc5957a92031a4d6c4d4/Python/ceval.c#L1175-L1186).

Last but not least, you pass that value to the `sys.getrefcount()` call.

If you want to learn about what references your objects, you may want to look at [`gc.get_referrers()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers); this function excludes itself and the stack when called, so you can mentally add +2:

```
>>> import gc
>>> def gc_demo():
...     x = 222677461248192962146784178
...     print(gc.get_referrers(x))
...
>>> gc_demo()
[(None, 222677461248192962146784178), <frame object at 0x106a25a98>]
```

That prints 2 objects; the `co_consts` tuple, and the current call frame (for the locals).

`py.test` does some additional [import-time magic](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/5721d8aed1f55703588923f5828ca49e731bc8bd/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py) which [rewrites `assert` statements](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/5721d8aed1f55703588923f5828ca49e731bc8bd/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py#L719-L769), and as a result the reference count is different again.

You may also want to read the [*Reference Counts* section](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#reference-counts) of the *Extending Python with C or C++* documentation, the [*Objects, Types and Reference Counts* section](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#objects-types-and-reference-counts) of the *C API Reference Manual*, and last but not least the [*Debugging Builds* section](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#debugging-builds) of the same same, to learn how to create a Python build that helps you trace reference counts in detail.

You should never rely on a specific number of references to an object. I can trivially add more references to you objects by reaching into the function object, for example (`foo = normal_te_st.__code__.co_conts[1]` would increment the reference count before even running the function). What exactly requires the reference count to go up is an implementation detail. Just make sure **your own code** handles references correctly.

Comment: thanks for the references, I need to chew on it, but this answer was what I was hoping for...